# Como recuperar la informacion de un varray de un procedure oracle desde c#?

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, matriz

alguien me puede ayudar con un ejemplo de como recuperar un varray(matriz de records personalizados) en oralce desde c#? el procedure de oracle funciona correctamente ya que lo he probado desde un bloque pl/sql y en el bloque pl/sql puedo declarar el varray del mismo tipo ya que puedo acceder al paquete, pero desde c# no se que tipo de dato le debo pasar al procedure.
El codigo siguiente es del bloque pl/sql con el que pruebo el procedure

```
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
    
    DECLARE    
        v_varray      pkg_1.typ_varray;
    BEGIN    
        --Inicializar variable para pruebas
            
        pkg_1.procedure_1(v_varray);
    
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Limite del VARRAY: '||v_varray.LIMIT);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Primer Indice: '||v_varray.FIRST);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Último Indice: '||v_varray.LAST);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cantidad de Registros en el Colección: '||v_varray.COUNT);    
    END;
```

Del lado c# en el metodo que se ejecuta al llamar al procedure de db tengo algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        query.Append("pkg_1.procedure_1");

        OracleParameter[] parameters = new OracleParameter[1];

        OracleParameter parameter1 = new OracleParameter();
        parameter1 .OracleType = OracleType.Cursor;
        parameter1 .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        parameter1 .ParameterName = "v_varray";
        parameters[0] = parameter1 ;

        DataSet ds = FactoryHelperData.ExecuteDatasetOracle(FactoryBaseData.ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, query.ToString(), parameters);
```

Y me manda el error que los tipos de datos enviados no son correctos ya que el OracleType lo tengo de tipo cursor.

Comment: Por favor agregue también el código de C# que tiene hasta el momento

Comment: Hola @RichardVíquezPérez, ya agregué código del lado de c#, gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo su código de paso le recomiendo usar el using: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement y también cosas que le pueden dar potencia a su código como el uso del async y el await: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/. El using le permite realizar las operaciones de la base de datos en un scope seguro. Un método para lo que necesita sería algo similar a esto,  el varray no es más que un arreglo de enteros en c# :

```
async Task Metodo(string conexion, int[] arrayEntero)
    {
        using (var con = new OracleConnection(conexion))
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "Nombre del store procedure aquí";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(
                "Nombre del parámetro aquí",
                OracleDbType.Array,
                arrayEntero,
                ParameterDirection.Input);

           await con.OpenAsync();            
           await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }
```